# Serialize data to json formate using native serializer Django

Tags: django, django-serializer

I have this dictionary which I need to pass to another view, knowing that possible ways of doing that are either through *sessions or cache*, now when I am trying to pass to session it is throwing me an error that data is not *JSON* serializable probably because I have *DateTime* fields inside this dictionary

```
  session_data = serializers.serialize('json',session_data)
```

**error on above statement**

```
'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

**updated**
date is somewhat in this format

```
{'city_name': 'Srinagar', 'description': 'few clouds', 'temp': 26.74, 'feels_like': 27.07, 'max_temp': 26.74, 'min_temp': 26.74, 'sunrise': datetime.time(6, 11, 10), 'sunset': datetime.time(18, 43, 59)}
```

Comment: You `session_data` seems to be a string already, not a model object.

Comment: not entirely it has some DateTime fields, it is a dictionary as I am passing it as a context to template as well

Comment: "_dictionary_" well there is your problem, `serializers.serialize` is supposed to be passed either a queryset or an iterable of _model instances_.

Comment: is there any way out of using any kind of serializer, or do i have to manually make changes because there is a lot of data and the process is tedious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `session_data` is already a dictionary. Since Django's serializer focuses on serializing an iterable of model object, that thus will not work.

You can make use of Django's [**`DjangoJSONEncoder`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/serialization/#django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder) to serialize Python objects that include `date`, `datetime`, `time` and/or `timedelta` objects.

You thus can work with:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

encoder = DjangoJSONEncoder()
session_data = encoder.encode(session_data)
```

If you plan to return a JSON blob as a HTTP response, you can simply let the `JsonResponse` do the encoding work:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

# …
return JsonResponse(session_data)
```